Is it true or false that in a topological ring, the direct limit of subspaces under inclusion (a single chain) has the topology induced by the ring?
Let $(R, \tau)$ be a topological ring and $A_1 \xrightarrow{i_1} A_2 \xrightarrow{i_2} \dots$ a sequence of subsets with directed system of inclusion maps $i_k$.
Each $A_i$ comes with its induced subspace topology via $\tau \cap A_i = \{ U\cap A_i : U \in \tau\}$. It's easy to see that the inclusion maps are continuous.
Now let $A = \lim_{\to} A_i$ performed in $\textbf{Top}$.  Then is it equal to $\tau \cap A$?
I'm not sure how topology of the direct limit works, so can't even begin...

No. You can verify that, if $A_1 \subset A_2 \subset \cdots$ is a chain of topological embeddings, then the direct limit $A = \lim_\to A_i$ has underlying set $\bigcup_i A_i$ and the topology given by $U \subset A$ is open iff $U \cap A_i$ is open in $A_i$ for all $i$. Now, counterexamples are easy to come by: let $A = R = \mathbb{Q}$ equipped with the usual topology. Let $A_i$ be an increasing sequence of finite subsets of $R$ whose union is $R$. Then the direct limit topology on $A = R$ is discrete, which is different from the given topology.
